# Loop isn't breaking when it encounters error

Tags: c++, loops, fstream

I have a file thats contains score for each person. The number of scores differs from line to line. I am trying to store the numbers into array for each person by doing `while(file>>array[i])` shouldn't the `while(file>>array[i])` break when it tries to read in words since I declared array as integer? What is the correct way to do this?

```
John Carter: 34 51 22 15 45
Ron Wilder: 32 33 23
John Carter: 1 2 3 4
Ron Wilder: 24 25 1 2 3 4
```

here is the logic. I will boundary check when this program works.

```
void storeNum(ifstream & file)
{
   int i =0, j= 0; 
   int JohnArray[10] = {0}; //store numbers for John
   int RonArray[10] = {0};    //Stores numbers for Ron
   string stringVariable;
   while (getline(file, stringVariable,':')) //file is a ifstream variable 
   {
      if (stringVariable == "John Carter")
      {
           while (file >> JohnArray[i])   //This should break when it encounter non integer
           {
                 i++; 
           }
           if (file.fail())
          {
              file.clear();     //clear fail bit
          }
      }
      else if (stringVariable == "Ron Wilder")
      {
          while (file >> RonArray[j])    //store numbers for Ron
           {
                 j++;
            }
           if (file.fail())
           {
               file.clear();   //clear failbit
            }
      }
      else 
       {
          continue;
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which is your problem? [Demo](https://ideone.com/NAVdFt)

Comment: Why do you think the program does not work? it seems to worksfine on my computer.

Comment: @Jarod42 get line was grabbing the number as well

Comment: @RSahu  its only displaying 0 when printing out the array. Edit: The names were spelled correctly in the file

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine. The name on the file wasn't spelled correctly

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use Exception Handling, pseudocode is:

```
try{
  //your_code, ie reading from file
}catch(exception){
  //print your error here
}
```

Comment: That works only when you expect the code to throw an exception. That's not true for the OP's code.

Comment: "`catch(exception)`" -  to prevent object slicing you usually want to always catch exceptions by (`const`) reference. So (also pseudo code), `catch(const& exception)`.